# Dynamic query call and connection string

Tags: excel, vba, automation

```
    Sub SavedConfiguration()

    Dim cnn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim iCols As Integer
    Const TABLE_NAME = "TableName"
    Const DRIVER = "{SQL Server}"

    Dim conf
    conf = Array("D11", "database", "D12", "server")

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsConfig As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, strConn As String, sQry As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsConfig = Worksheets("Settings")
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("SavedConfig")

    ' construct connection string
    strConn = "driver=" & DRIVER & ";"
    For i = 1 To UBound(conf) Step 2
        strConn = strConn & conf(i) & "=" & wsConfig.Range(conf(i - 1)).Value & ";"
    Next

'    Debug.Print strConn
    sQry = Worksheets("SQL-COMMON").Range("B3").Value

    ' connect to db and run sql
    Set cnnl = New ADODB.Connection
        cnnl.ConnectionString = strConn
        cnnl.ConnectionTimeout = 30
        cnnl.Open




    wsConfig.Range("H35") = Now

    ' output
    mrs.Open sQry, cnn1
    For iCols = 0 To mrs.Fields.Count - 1
        wsOut.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = mrs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    Worksheets("SavedConfig").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

    wsConfig.Range("D35") = Now

    mrs.Close
    cnn1.Close
End Sub
```

I have edited the code, am getting unspecified error while executing it
How to make the connection string more dynamic instead of hard coding above, and picking up the values from cells of the worksheet of excel. 
How to add the code for showing the Last run start time and date and last run end time and date of the query which is being executed, getting tabulated automatically in the excel cells.

Comment: So do you know how to return a recordset to a range, but not know how to read from a range?

Comment: I know both, but read my question carefully, I am asking for the DB connection string. To elaborate picking up DB name value from cell A12, server name from A13, P/w from A14 and so on.

Comment: So why not reverse engineer what you have to put the field names in to extract from a range?  Or use what you know?

Comment: The cell has a named reference, how to use it. I was looking for a code solution.

Comment: What is the sheet name of A12:A14 . Which cell is user id uid ? "Tabulated automatically" in which cells ?

Comment: Sheet name is Sheet1. You can ignore user id uid and password. Tabulated automatically means - LAST RUN STARTED (H35) and LAST RUN COMPLETED(D35) in Sheet 1

Comment: Sheet name is Sheet1. You can ignore user id uid and password. Tabulated automatically means - LAST RUN STARTED (H35) and LAST RUN COMPLETED(D35) in Sheet 1

Answer (score 0):

Build the connection string by concatenating each parameter.

```vb
Sub Conn2SQL()

    Const TABLE_NAME = "TableName"
    Const DRIVER = "{SQL Server}"

    Dim conf
    conf = Array("A12", "database", "A13", "server", _
                 "A14", "password", "A15", "uid")

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsConfig As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, strConn As String, sQry As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsConfig = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("SavedConfig")

    ' construct connection string
    strConn = "driver=" & DRIVER & ";"
    For i = 1 To UBound(conf) Step 2
        strConn = strConn & conf(i) & "=" & wsConfig.Range(conf(i - 1)).Value & ";"
    Next
    'Debug.Print strConn
    sQry = "SELECT * FROM [" & TABLE_NAME & "]"

    ' connect to db and run sql
    Dim cnn1 As New ADODB.Connection, mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim iCols As Integer
    With cnn1
        .ConnectionString = strConn
        .ConnectionTimeout = 30
        .Open
    End With
    wsConfig.Range("H35") = "LAST RUN STARTED " & Now
    cnn1.Execute "USE " & wsConfig.Range(conf(0))

    ' output
    mrs.Open sQry, cnn1
    For iCols = 0 To mrs.Fields.Count - 1
        wsOut.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = mrs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    wsOut.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset mrs 'A2
    wsConfig.Range("D35") = "LAST RUN COMPLETED " & Now

    i = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox i & " rows added to " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation
    mrs.Close
    cnn1.Close
End Sub
```

Test the connection string with this code

```vb
Sub testconnect()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset, s As String
    s = "" ' put connection string here

    With conn
        .ConnectionString = s
        .ConnectionTimeout = 30
        .Open
    End With
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    MsgBox "Time is " & rs(0), vbOKOnly
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting Automation error while executing the code. When I debugged the code found out that in the with condition after open it goes into error.
I am using Excel 2016 FYI

Comment: The string is passed correctly however, after open it fails to execute further

Comment: I have posted the code I am using, please review and let me know

Comment: THere is no username or password required for the connection to my database

Comment: The time and date are displayed

Comment: @VinamraMathur check your variable cnn1 some appear to have a lower case L instead of 1.

Comment: I checked and made the changes still it shows the error

Comment: @VinamraMathur Your code works for me, it could be the SQL., test it with  sQry = "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: Can you tell me what all references have you checked on? Go to Tools -> References